# Htaccess Redirect from subdirectory to root

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm looking for a htaccess code to redirect my url's like this :

```
http://01.mydomain.com/subdir/xyz [OR]
http://www.01.mydomain.com/subdir/xyz [OR]
http://02.mydomain.com/subdir/xyz [OR]
http://www.02.mydomain.com/subdir/xyz
TO : http://www .mydomain.com/xyz
```

and in this case `xyz` is dynamic and could be any value. and `subdir` is constant

Comment: Well you know, this is a forum to help you with specific problems you have. To help you in case you tried something and don#t understand why it does not work. This is _not_ a forum to have others make your homework. Read the documentation! It is execellent!

Comment: oh come on, play nice, @NOjAN is clearly having difficulties with regex/rewrites, as I'm sure many people do.

Comment: @arkascha i looked at apache mod_rewrite documentation. it's well documented, but for a beginner like me it's very hard to find out a solution. and this is an urgent matter. but you're right.

Comment: Sorry, I certinaly did not want to step on anyones feet. But simply asking "do this for me" is wrong. You will never learn that way. And especially the note that this is "an urgent matter"... There are millions, no millions of millions of excellent examples and tutorials out there on google. None of those were suitable to be understood? Sorry, I don't believe that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `subdir` is constant, the following is one way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^01.mydomain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.01.mydomain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^02.mydomain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.02.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^subdir/(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^/subdir/(.*)/?$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: your solution didn't changed the subdomain for some reason! maybe it has a conflict with vbseo plugin that i have on my forum. but Jason's code worked perfectly. i appreciate your help anyway.